# Bezier path moving during animation when it should not

Tags: animation

Stupid beginners question concerning animation.  I have four spheres which I would like to move along four bezier paths.  Three of them work correctly but in the case of the fourth the bezier curve ALSO moves: somehow the motion of that sphere in the Y axis has been replaced by the bezier curve moving in the Y axis instead.

I can't for the life of me determine what setting I've accidentally clicked on to make that happen.  Can anyone help me out?  This is in Blender 2.79b.

The Blender file can be downloaded from One Drive here:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqUHa_qo4gdB9W1TZWpmNt9v8yCe?e=46GmLD

It is "Suck Curve 2" carrying the animated sphere "Suck Sphere 2" which is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

- <kbd>F3</kbd> and type *Remove Animation*.
- You can delete the animation in the *Outliner*: Select the object, unfold its tree, right click on *Animation* and choose *Clear Animation Data*.
- Open the *Dopesheet*, switch it to *Action Editor* mode, you have a dropdown menu with all your animations, close the selected animation with X.

As your curve was the only user of this animation, it won't be reloaded when you'll reopen the file. If you don't want to loose it, in the *Dopesheet* / *Action Editor* mode, on the right of the action name (it has now a 0 which means no user), press on the shield icon.

Comment: Ah, yes, clear the animation data for the curve.  Since it was only the spheres I was animating, how come the curves all have animation data attached to them?  Does an "empty" animation node get added to the curves as well?

Comment: maybe you had the curve selected when you selected the animation in the Dopesheet?

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm starting to get it now, apologies for the stupid question, just gotta think "Blender UI". :-)

Comment: yes it's very disturbing at the beginning